# Lambda function variables in C++11

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, closures

There are two ways to use lambda function variable:

```
std::function<int(int, int)> x1 = [=](int a, int b) -> int{return a + b;};

//usage
void set(std::function<int(int, int)> x);
std::function<int(int, int)> get();
```

And:

```
std::function<int(int, int)>* x2 = new std::function<int(int, int)>([=](int a, int b) -> int{return a + b;});

//usage
void set(std::function<int(int, int)>* x);
std::function<int(int, int)>* get();
```

I would like to know what are the differences, because I do not know how the lambda function data is stored.

I would like to know the best way in terms of peformance, memory usage and the best way to pass a lambda function as argument or return lambda function.
I would prefer to use pointers if the size of the lambda function object is bigger than 4 or to avoid errors (if some kind of copy constructor is executed when I do an attribution or if some kind of destructor is executed when I do not want).

How should I declare lambda function variables?

**EDIT**

I want to avoid copies and moves, I want to continue to use the same function again.

How should I change this example?

```
int call1(std::function<int(int, int)> f){
    return f(1, 2);
}
int call2(std::function<int(int, int)> f){
    return f(4, 3);
}
std::function<int(int, int)>& recv(int s){
    return [=](int a, int b) -> int{return a*b + s;};
}

int main(){
    std::function<int(int, int)> f1, f2;

    f1 = [=](int a, int b) -> int{return a + b;};
    f2 = recv(10);

    call1(f1);
    call2(f1);
    call1(f2);
    call2(f2);
}
```

I cannot return reference in the function recv:

```
 warning: returning reference to temporary
```

Is this a good solution?

```
int call1(std::function<int(int, int)>* f){
    return (*f)(1, 2);
}
int call2(std::function<int(int, int)>* f){
    return (*f)(4, 3);
}

std::function<int(int, int)>* recv(int s){
    return new std::function<int(int, int)>([=](int a, int b) -> int{return a*b + s;});
}

int main(){
    std::function<int(int, int)> f1 = [=](int a, int b) -> int{return a + b;};
    std::function<int(int, int)> *f2 = recv(10);

    call1(&f1);
    call2(&f1);
    call1(f2);
    call2(f2);

    delete f2;
}
```

**EDIT (Conclusion)**

A lambda function object is like any object that is instance of a class. The rules for allocation, arguments and attribution are the same.

Comment: "I would prefer to use pointers if the size of the lambda function object is bigger than 4" Why? Do you think the stack will implode if an object larger than 4 bytes is on it? Standard C++ practice is to put objects on the stack by *default*, unless you have a good reason not to. And being larger than 4 bytes isn't one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've made it clear that you want to use pointers. So... do that.

But at least use a *smart* pointer. Proper use of `std::shared_ptr` would prevent a number of problems. Of course, you have to make sure to avoid circular references, but for lambdas, that seems unlikely.

Granted, it's still a terrible idea. But it's only terrible in the sense of being a completely pointless premature optimization done to make yourself feel better about passing things around, rather than having any actual measurable benefit in your code's actual running time. At least with a `shared_ptr`, you're less likely to accidentally delete the memory or run into exception safety issues.

---

I'm going to ignore the bad C++ practice of heap-allocating something you could just as easily stack allocate, as well as the pain of tracking this memory without the use of a smart pointer. This will assume that you know what you're doing and will instead focus on the "performance" and "memory usage" issues you asked about.

Do not take this as an endorsement of what you're wanting to do.

`std::function` will generally be implemented by doing an internal heap allocation of some object; that's necessary due to the type-erasure. So it will be at least one pointer in size; possibly more. The size of the heap allocation will likely be a vtable pointer + the size of your lambda class. And the size of that is governed by how much stuff you capture and whether it is by value or reference.

Like most C++ standard library objects, `std::function` is copyable. Performing a copy will actually *copy* it, not do a pretend copy where you now have two objects with the same pointer. So each one will have an independent copy of the internal heap object. That is, copying it will mean doing another heap allocation. This will also copy the lambda itself, which means copying everything that's captured within it.

However, like most C++ standard library objects, `std::function` is *movable*. This does *not* do any memory allocation whatsoever.

Therefore, if you want to do this, it's pretty cheap:

```
std::function<int(int, int)> x1 = [=](int a, int b) -> int{return a + b;};

//usage
void set(std::function<int(int, int)> x);
const std::function<int(int, int)> &get();

set(std::move(x1)); //x1 is now *empty*; you can't use it anymore.
```

Your `set` function can move it into its own internal storage as needed. Note that `get` now returns a `const&`; this is contingent on the storage for these functions not going anywhere.

How cheap will `move` be? It will probably be the equivalent of copying just the fields of `std::function`, as well as blanking or otherwise neutralizing the original one. Unless you're in performance-critical code, this will not be anything you should ever be concerned about.

Comment: I cannot return reference allocated on stack. I cannot use move, because I will need to use the function again, I think that traditional pointer would help.

Comment: @Squall: You `get` function would presumably be retrieving it from some storage, like the member of an object or something. And if not, then just return a value and let NVRO or move-construction take care of it, since you're talking about a stack parameter. And no, the "traditional pointer" is not helpful (and isn't "traditional" in C++ anymore). All it will do is create more bugs. If you still need to use the object, then use it *beforehand* or just *copy* it. Otherwise, you have to sort out who owns it, which without smart pointers is very error prone. Not to mention exception safety.

Comment: @Squall: It seems to me that you've already decided on what you want to do, but you know it's not kosher, and are trying to find validation for your plan. If you are willing to ignore everyone's advice and just heap-allocate them into naked pointers and do the "traditional" thing (including the traditional memory leaks, double-deletion, and lack of exception safety), then *do it*. If you want actual advice, then copy the object and/or move it, as you need to. Or at the *very* least, use a smart pointer.

Answer (score 23):

It doesn't make sense to create pointer of `std::function`. It just doesn't benefit you in any way. Instead of benefits, it puts more burden on you, as you've to delete the memory.

So the first version (i.e the non-pointer version) is all that you should go for.

In general, like a rule of thumb, **avoid** `new` as much as possible.

Also, you don't need `std::function` everytime you use lambda. Many times, you could just use `auto` as:

```
auto add = [](int a, int b) { return a + b;};

std::cout << add(100,100) << std::endl;
std::cout << add(120,140) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Also, passing things on the stack is usually much faster than allocating things on the free store and passing pointers to them and having to apply indirection.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie And you won't have any headaches because of manual memory management and exception-unsafety.

Comment: "Many times" is a bit of a stretch. He obviously wants to store it somewhere else, hence is accessor functions.

Comment: If I need to pass a lambda function as argument or return a lambda function, should I use pointers?

Comment: @Squall: NO. Use the first version.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the guidelines I tend to follow with the "functional C++" these new lambda expressions (plus std::function & std::bind) give you. Feel free to ignore them or adopt them as you see fit:

1) Assign any lambda you want to have a name as a std::function. If you're passing it into some function "X(..)" and never looking at it again, declare it in the function call so that "X" can take advantage of the fact that it is a temporary.

```
// I want a real name for this (plan to use multiple times, etc.)
// Rarely are you going to do this without moving the lambda around, so
// declaring it as 'auto' is pointless because C++ APIs expect a real type.

std::function<double(double)> computeAbs = [](double d) -> double { return fabs(d); };

// Here, we only ever use the lambda for the call to "X".
// So, just declare it inline. That will enforce our intended usage and probably
// produce more efficient code too.

X([](double r) -> double { return fabs(r); });
```

2) If you plan to move functions all over the place, use some sort of reference-counted wrapper around std::function. The idea is to pass around a safe pointer to the actual std::function, thus avoiding costly copies as well as worrying about new and delete.

Building your own class for doing this can be a pain, but it will ensure you only take the hit for actually converting your lambda, function ptr, etc. into a std::function once. 
You can then provide an API like "GetFunction" to return the std::function you carry by value for APIs that expect them.

3) For public APIs taking std::function or lambdas, just pass by value.

Yes, you CAN get passing by reference or even r-value (those '&&') references to work and they're even the right solution in some situations. But lambdas are nasty in that their actual type is literally unknowable to you. However, they are all convertible to std::function in the same way that all primitive types can convert to 'int', so passing them into functions involves using the same tricks that let you pass chars and floats into a function like "f(int a)".

Namely, you create functions "f" that are either templated on the TYPE of the functor argument like:

```
template<typename Functor>
double f(Functor absFunc);
```

OR, you make everybody normalize to std::function:

```
double f(std::function<double(double)> absFunc);
```

Now, when you call "f([](double r) -> double { return fabs(r); })" the compiler knows to how to handle it. Users get something that 'just works' without having to code around your API, which is what you want.

Comment: +1: However poorly this may be written and formatted (n.b., _very_), it is still a thoughtful answer that should merit no less than the votes given to an unwieldy question.